# Why are hooks (except hook_help) not working?

Tags: hooks

```
<?php
function webformta_init() {
    dsm('hello world');
}
```

does absolutely nothing.

```
<?php
   dsm('hello world');
```

sets an alert message with the text "hello world".

I've tried wrapping this in several hooks. Hook_load, hook_node_load, you name it.

But somehow, oddly, hook_help seems to be working.

```
function webformta_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#webformta":
      return '<p>'.  t("Grades quizzes like a TA. Works with Webform.") .'</p>';
      break;
  }
}
```

creates a nice little help link in the module list and outputs the text and everything.

What did I screw up?

Comment: You need to clear the cache after adding new hooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear the cache after adding new hooks.